# PHP - retrieve a base64 string from Database

Tags: php

Here's the class that retrieves the string from the database. The database contains the URL of where the JPG image file is located. This class finds the URL out from the database, encode the image into the base64 string, and returns the string value.

```
<?php

class GetImage {
    private $conn;

    function __construct() {
        require_once 'include/db_connect.php';

        $db = new DB_CONNECT();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    function __destruct() {

    }

    public function getEncodedImageByUid($uid) {
        $query = $this->conn->query("SELECT profile_image FROM users WHERE unique_id = '$uid'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $imageUrl = $row['profile_image'];
            if(!empty($imageUrl)) {
                $base64image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($imageUrl));
                $result = $base64image;
            } else {
                $result = '';
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

?>
```

Now, in the other file, I will create an instance of the class above and get the string. Here's the part of the code.

```
require_once 'getimage.php';
$getImage = new GetImage();
$encodedImage = $getImage->getEncodedImageByUid($senderUid);
if(!strcmp($encodedImage, '')) {
    $payload['encoded_image'] = $encodedImage;
} else {
    $payload['encoded_image'] = '';
}
```

After running the programme, I get the empty result from the client side. How should I fix this one?

Comment: Did you have any checkpoints along the way? Do you get a legitimate `$image Url`? Does PHP have access to where the image is stored? Is the image file content being retrieved successfully?

Comment: I just checked out, and I even failed to get the `URL` itself.

Comment: `echo $payload['encoded_image']` ??

Comment: Your title suggests you are retrieving a base64 string from database but you are retrieving an URL.